# django template tag missing 1 required positional argument : value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, templatetags

In my django project, I have custom template tag to set correct next link in pagination:

```
@register.tag(name='url_replace')
def url_replace(request, field, value):
   print('this is form tag',request,field,value)
   d = request.GET.copy()
   d[field] = value
   return d.urlencode()
```

In my template:

```
  {% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.previous_page_number %}">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == i %}
          <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' i %}">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.next_page_number %}">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

Looks every thing fine but it is showing me error:

> Exception Value:
> url_replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

I'm unable to figure out the problem as I passed all three arguments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `@register.tag` to `@register.simple_tag`. @register.tag is something bit more complicated

compare 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag
with 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag

Answer (score 0):

You should use [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) whose function can get the values from the template tag as shown below, then the error is solved. *[@register.tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag)'s function cannot get the values but can get the tokens from the template tag and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76246817/register-simple-tag-vs-register-tag-vs-register-inclusion-tag-in-django-templ/76246818#76246818) explaining more about `@register.simple_tag` and `@register.tag`:

```py
# @register.tag(name='url_replace')
@register.simple_tag(name='url_replace')
def url_replace(request, field, value):
    # ...
```

```
             #        Values
             #      ↓    ↓    ↓
{% url_replace request 'page' i %}
```

In addition, `@register.tag`'s function must have `parser` as the 1st parameter and `token` as the 2nd parameter in convention (other names are fine) otherwise there is an error.:

```py
@register.tag(name='url_replace')
def url_replace(parser, token):
               #  ↑       ↑
               # 2 parameters
```